# How can I stretch my pyplot to make markers more discernible?

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

I'm really new to Python, so I'm sorry in advance if I'm missing a really obvious answer.  For my first code, I made a graph to compile data. However, one of the data sets I put into it was too close together and it was hard to discern between the markers, so I need to stretch out the graph to widen it. I've already tried this:

`fig.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0)
fig.subplots_adjust(top = 1)
fig.subplots_adjust(right = 1)
fig.subplots_adjust(left = 0)`

but it doesn't expand it enough and I always end up with this:
[image]

I've searched everywhere for a solution, including the matplotlib documentation, but I can't find a solution anywhere. Does anyone know of an answer? Sorry again if I'm missing something obvious,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completely sure if this is the kind of thing you're looking for, but `legend()` inside `matplotlib.pyplot` may be able to help you out.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
p1 = plt.plot(data1)
p2 = plt.plot(data2)
plt.legend([p1, p2], ["Data 1", "Data 2"])
```

In general, once you have adjusted the axes so that the data fills up all possible space, you can't do too much about the squishing except color different curves differently, and put a legend.

You can also try setting the [y-limits of the plot](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ylim) using `ylim`

```
ymin, ymax = ylim()   # return the current ylim
ylim( (ymin, ymax) )  # set the ylim to ymin, ymax
ylim( ymin, ymax )    # set the ylim to ymin, ymax
```

Comment: Thanks, it didn't completely fix the problem but it did stretch it out enough.